# Can we connect a DAQ to a micro-controller via a CAN bus?

Tags: arduino, can, daq

I want to establish communication between an Arduino to a DAQ that I am using from DEWESOFT called the Dewe 43-A. The DAQ has 2 CAN bus ports according to its specs, and I was wondering if I can connect it to an Arduino using them via a CAN bus, or is there another way I can do so?

DAQ user manual: https://d36j349d8rqm96.cloudfront.net/3/6/DEWE-43_user%20manual.pdf

Comment: You'll need a CAN transceiver connected to the Arduino; try using your favorite search engine to the tune of 'arduino can module.'

Answer (score 0):

Hardware aspects: http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/arduino-can-bus-module-1st-network-tutorial/ should give a hint. It is about adding CAN tranceiver to the Arduino.

Software concepts:
What is the needed bandwidth? Depending on that Arduino might not be able to deliver all the data or process all of it. What is the final goal? Should Arduino process it and take action? Or transmit to other device. If the thoughout needed is less, then basic CAN bus with Arduino will work .. else you have to go with a powerful microcontroller

Answer (score 0):

The linked manual doesn't say much about the CAN protocol used. Adapting to the protocol is going to be the major obstacle here, not the hardware. Ask for documentation over the protocol.

As for hardware, Arduino is unsuitable but can be used. Arduino requires an external CAN controller, like it was done in the 1990s. It is better and far less painful to pick a modern 32 bit MCU with CAN controller on-board.